# grid is not loading with searched json data in ExtJs4

Tags: grid, extjs4

I have form panel with form and grid.

My grid is loaded with JSON data of 120 rows and the form with 5 combo fields to search for required row.

Now,when I click on search button PHP script is returning correct JSON data but this data is not loaded in the grid.

I am new to ExtJs4 plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

U have paste some code of ur application to let me know how u load Json into grid and how u would like to filter the grid's row.

Anyway if i well understand the grid don't show the Json data?

Have u set a store for the grid and load into store by PHP the Json file?

Ref:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy